# Question about Cauchy-Kowalevsky theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have the following Cauchy problem:

$u_x+u_y=u^2$

$u(x,0)=h(x)$

The solution I got is: $u(x,y)=$$h(x-y)\over{1-yh(x-y)}$

If h is analytic, what can I conclude applying Cauchy-Kowalesky theorem? That there exists a unique analytic solution of the problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a unique analytic solution in a (small) neighbourhood of the $x$-axis.

Comment: Do we need any more hypothesis  to conclude that or is it enough with h being analytic?

Comment: It is enough. Just FYI, the theory of first order semilinear equations would give you a stronger uniqueness result.